# k-clustering problems

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, clustering

I'm interested in open questions from the book [Approximation Algorithms for NP-Hard Problems](http://www.ieor.berkeley.edu/~hochbaum/html/book-aanp.html)s dedicated to k-clustering. They are:

> Is Euclidean max cut solvable in polynomial time? If not, how well can
>   it be approximated?
>
> Does the problem minimizing the sum of distances from points to their
>   cluster centers has good approximation algorithm ?

Answer (score 7):

The problem of minimizing the sum of distances from points to cluster centers is called the $k$-median problem. In a general metric space, the $k$-median can be approximated to within a factor of $3+\epsilon$ and is $\mathsf{MAX SNP}$-hard. In Euclidean space, the problem admits a PTAS. [This is a good survey](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~shindler/shindler-kMedian-survey.pdf) and has references for the above facts.

Comment: Do you have a reference of the paper that show MAXSNP-hardness? The survey that you pointed out mentions this result but doesn't cite any paper.

Comment: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=510012 (Jain/Mahdian/Saberi, STOC 2002)